Free-Field Construction of the Virasoro Algebra
The Virasoro algebra is given by the relation
$$
[L_m, L_n] = (m-n)L_{m+n} + \frac{c}{12}m(m^2 -1)\delta_{m,-n}.
$$
Also consider a free spin-1 field in 1+1 dimensions (which is invariant under conformal transformations, but that is secondary now), written in terms of Fourier modes as
$$
J(\theta) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_ke^{-ik\theta}
$$
Where the modes fulfil the relation
$$
[J_m,J_n] = m\delta_{m,-n}.
$$
Note that this implies that the bracket of any mode with $J_0$ vanishes. Now, according to my professor one can construct the generators $L_m$ from the modes $J_k$ above as
$$
L_m = -im\alpha J_m + \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_kJ_{m-k}
$$
Where $\alpha$ is some parameter of the theory, yet to be determined. I have managed to derive this expression from the modes of the energy-momentum tensor of the field $J(\theta)$ (again in accordance with the hints from my professor), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how this expression is supposed to fulfil the above Virasoro relation. On the one hand, we have
$$
(m-n)L_{m+n}+ \frac{c}{12}m(m^2 -1)\delta_{m,-n} = -i\alpha(m-n)(m+n)J_{m+n} + (m-n)\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_kJ_{m+n-k}+ \frac{c}{12}m(m^2 -1)\delta_{m,-n}
$$
While on the other, we have for the bracket
$$
[L_m, L_n] = \left[-im\alpha J_m + \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_kJ_{m-k},-in\alpha J_n + \sum_{l\in\Bbb Z}J_lJ_{n-l}\right]
$$
Which expands to
$$
-mn\alpha^2[J_m,J_n] - i\alpha\left(\left[J_m,\sum_{l\in\Bbb Z}J_lJ_{n-l}\right]+\left[\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_kJ_{m-k}, J_n\right]\right) + \left[\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}J_kJ_{m-k},\sum_{l\in\Bbb Z}J_lJ_{n-l}\right].
$$
The term with coefficient $i\alpha$ gives the corresponding term in the Virasoro relation, along with an additional factor of two that I will worry about later. Likewise, the last bracket gives, after some algebra and shifting around indices, twice the term containing a sum. Again, I will worry about this constant factor later.
The real issue is the first bracket, from which we get the $\delta_{m,-n}$: In the Virasoro algebra, this term comes with a factor that contains a sum of different powers of $m$, while in my version, it only contains a product of $m$ and $n$. By exploiting the symmetry of the bracket of the $J_k$, one can at least replace the $n$ by an $m$, but I have no idea where the additional $m\delta_{m,-n}$ (which would correspond to an extra $[J_m, J_n]$) comes from. Is there a trick I am missing? Am I even going about this the right way? Is the additional factor of two related to all of this, does it originate from a mistake, or can I explain it away by properly choosing my $\alpha$?

The standard Sugawara construction for a $\mathfrak{u}(1)_1$ Kac-Moody algebra has $\alpha=0$, and a factor of $1/2$ (related to this factor of $2$ that worries you) in the definition of $L_m$.
